# sql server management studio 2012 diagram relationships nice look

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create some nice relationship diagrams using sql server management studio 2012.

Standard types are looking bad for me.

1. I would like to remove header "column name, condensed type" from table view
2. I do not want to see empty row at the bottom
3. I do not want margins (when using "autosize selected tables")

Here's the way my diagram looks:
[image]

Are there any plugins or ways to edit standard views?

Are there some modern looking diagrams?

@edit:
Insted of SQL server management studio I have used DBVIS and it did the trick.

Comment: I think you would need a third party or Visio maybe to do what your are trying to do... This is not doable in Management Studio

Comment: Are you just trying to [change the view](http://i.imgur.com/ya2Fq8A.png) in SSMS (this is a 2008 screen)?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO thank you for editing my image link - I could not do it myself (I did not had enought reputation). Under Table view->modify custom you can only add or remove columns. I want to remove column headers (they are added automaticlly - "column name, condensed type" etc.). This is screen from 2012 (I think that the only difference between 2008 is table name font)

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in Visio to [reverse engineer a SQL Server database](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/reverse-engineer-an-existing-database-into-a-database-model-HA010115485.aspx?CTT=1), unfortunately it was dropped for Visio 2013 so you would have to use a previous version. Once you reverse engineer it, you would be able to modify it in whichever way you need.